# swift 2.0 which image was assigned

Tags: swift, image, random

I would like to know how to check which image was assigned to a SKSpriteNode.

Here is my code:
updated feb11

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */

       self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

    }//enddidMoveToView

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
       /* Called when a touch begins */
        print("hello")
        var ball = SKSpriteNode()
        for touch in touches {

            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
            //calls a ball with a randomImgColor
            ball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"ball\(arc4random_uniform(3))")
            ball.xScale = 0.1
            ball.yScale = 0.1
            ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius:  ball.size.height / 2.5)
            ball.position = location

            if ball == SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"ball0") {
                print("the red ball was assigned")
            } else if ball == SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"ball1") {
                print("the green ball was assigned")
            } else if ball == SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"ball2") {
                print("the blue ball was assigned")
            }

            self.addChild(ball) 
        }//ends touch
    }//endtouchesBegan


    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    }


}//end GameScene
```

Comment: updated, see if my new solution gets you anywhere

Comment: perfect exactly what I was looking for thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution for you but it might not be what you were looking for. Since your creating an image by passing a randomized string into `SKSpriteNode`, you can instead store the string in a variable and set the `SKSpriteNotes` `.name` property to the *same exact thing* and then check the value of name. This saves you the trouble of creating instances to check against:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches {
            var ball = SKSpriteNode() // in your for loop!
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
            let random = "ball\(arc4random_uniform(3))" // <-- notice
            ball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:random)
            ball.xScale = 0.1
            ball.yScale = 0.1
            ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius:  ball.size.height / 2.5)
            ball.name = random // <-- set name == to your ball type
            ball.position = location

            // safely unwrap ball name
            guard let ballName = ball.name else {
                return
            }
            print(ballName)
            // check ball name
            if ballName == "ball0" {
                print("the red ball was assigned")
            } else if ballName == "ball1" {
                print("the green ball was assigned")
            } else if ballName == "ball2" {
                print("the blue ball was assigned")
            }

            self.addChild(ball)
        }
    }//ends touch
```

---

**original post:**

Your conditional logic is mixed up, you're missing a curly brace:

```
if ball == SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"ball0") {
    print("the red ball was assigned")
} else if ball == SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"ball1") {
    print("the green ball was assigned")
} else if ball == SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"ball2") {
    print("the blue ball was assigned")
}
```

Although I can't be sure what your intentions are but I'm thinking you want your conditional statement inside your for in loop correct?

```
for touch in touches {
    let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

    //calls a ball with a randomImgColor
    ball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"ball\(arc4random_uniform(3))")
    ball.position = location

    if ball == SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"ball0") {
        print("the red ball was assigned")
    } else if ball == SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"ball1") {
        print("the green ball was assigned")
    } else if ball == SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"ball2") {
        print("the blue ball was assigned")
    }

    self.addChild(ball) 
}
```

Comment: Will do for sure. First time using this service and I'v very impressed, So glad there are people like you in this world :)

Comment: I must have been mistaken. I thought the logic made sense reading your code but I'm not getting any prints. Could there be a cause for this @dan-beaulieu

Comment: Add a print statement to the top of your "touchesEnded" function to make sure it fires.